# How can sed add text after existing indent?

Tags: sed

I have a sed script that has:

```
sed -i '/ *it.*do/! {
          /\.should/ {
            s/\.should/)\.to/
            s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/ 
            # ...others
```

The last `s` adds `expect(` to the start of the line.  I don't understand how it works.

It works though for:

Original:

```
  it "uses the given count if set" do
    call('5').should == 5
  end

  it "uses the processor count from Parallel" do
    call(nil).should == 20
  end
```

After:

```
  it "uses the given count if set" do
    expect(call('5')).to eq 5
  end

  it "uses the processor count from Parallel" do
    expect(call(nil)).to eq 20
  end
```

But it doesn't add the `expect(` for:

Original:

```
  it "does not wait if not run in parallel" do
    ParallelTests.should_not_receive(:sleep)
    ParallelTests.wait_for_other_processes_to_finish
  end

  it "stops if only itself is running" do
    ENV["TEST_ENV_NUMBER"] = "2"
    ParallelTests.should_not_receive(:sleep)
    with_running_processes(1) do
        ParallelTests.wait_for_other_processes_to_finish
      end
  end
```

After - no `expect(`...

```
  it "does not wait if not run in parallel" do
    ParallelTests).to_not receive(:sleep)
    ParallelTests.wait_for_other_processes_to_finish
  end

  it "stops if only itself is running" do
    ENV["TEST_ENV_NUMBER"] = "2"
    ParallelTests).to_not receive(:sleep)
    with_running_processes(1) do
        ParallelTests.wait_for_other_processes_to_finish
      end
  end
```

However it **DOES** work for:
After:

```
  it "should be true when there is a Gemfile" do
    use_temporary_directory_for do
      FileUtils.touch("Gemfile")
      expect(ParallelTests.send(:bundler_enabled?)).to eq true
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why should it work? It only puts in the `expect(` for lines that match `\.should`.

Comment: `.should_not_receive` does match `\.should`, and the 2 replacements shown result in `expect(ParallelTests).to_not_receive(:sleep)`. Something in `# ...others` must be the problem.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley You're right, I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a [character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes), since you do not have the `-r` flag set the `\(` and `\)` makes a group for latter reference, and `\S` is just the complementary group for `\s`, since `\s` is the group that matches any white-space `\S` is the group that matches anything but white-space.

This means that the regex `s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/` adds `expect(` on front of the first non white-space:

```
# echo ' ' | sed "s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/"

# echo '   a' | sed "s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/"
   expect(a
```

So, I guess that I'm trying to say that your script does change the line:

```
ParallelTests.should_not_receive(:sleep)
```

It must change it:

```
# echo "ParallelTests.should_not_receive(:sleep)" | sed '/ *it.*do/! {
    /\.should/ {
        s/\.should/)\.to/
        s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/ 
    }
}'
expect(ParallelTests).to_not_receive(:sleep)
```